# Adding `or` on `has_many` association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have these models and I want to get all the addresses of both `customer_x` and `customer_y` through the assoc `has_many :addresses`.

Is there a method or something that can modify the `has_many :addresses` to add a codition `OR` in the query?

```rb
# customer.rb
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses
end

# customer_x.rb
class CustomerX < Customer
  has_many :customer_ys
end

# customer_y.rb
class CustomerY < Customer
  belongs_to :customer_x, foreign_key: :customer_x_id
end

# address.rb
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

I tried this but of course it will only return all the addresses belonging to `customer_id 1`.

```rb
customer = Customer.first
customer.addresses
=> SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE customer_id = 1
```

What I want is to add `OR` in the condition statement like this:

```rb
=> SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE customer_id = 1 OR customer_x_id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

customer_x = Customer.find(1)

customer_y = Customer.find(2)

This will give you the addresses of customer_x or customer_y

```
address_of_custormers_x_or_y = customer_x.addresses.or(customer_y.addresses)
```

Comment: I think you missed the "I want to get all the addresses of both customer_x and customer_y through the assoc has_many :addresses" part. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this design looks very complicated. If You still want to use same way then take a look at following hack.

It works if you are not using `STI` here.

```
  # customer.rb
  class Customer < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :addresses

    def addresses
       if self.type == 'customer_x'
         adrs = []
         self.customer_ys.each do|c|
           adrs << c.addresses
         end
         adrs << super
         return adrs
       else
         super
       end
    end
  end

  # customer_x.rb
  class CustomerX < Customer
    has_many :customer_ys
  end

 # customer_y.rb
 class CustomerY < Customer
   belongs_to :customer_x, foreign_key: :customer_x_id
 end

 # address.rb
 class Address < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :customer
 end
```

else if you are using STI. You need to move the addresses method to `customer_x.rb` class, as follows

```
  # customer.rb
  class Customer < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :addresses
  end

  # customer_x.rb
  class CustomerX < Customer
    has_many :customer_ys

    def addresses
       adrs = []
       self.customer_ys.each do|c|
         adrs << c.addresses
       end
       adrs << super
       adrs
    end
  end

 # customer_y.rb
 class CustomerY < Customer
   belongs_to :customer_x, foreign_key: :customer_x_id
 end

 # address.rb
 class Address < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :customer
 end
```

But if you observe carefully the `addresses` method, we are making one query for every customer_y for addresses to fetch. Instead if you want you can change that method to following way.

```
    def addresses
       cus_ids = self.customer_ys.pluck(:id)
       cus_ids << self.id
       Address.Where(customer_id: cus_ids)
    end
```

JFYI: Its my friend Rahul's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple where condition on address like below,

```
Address.where(customer_id: :customer_ids, customer_ids: [1,2])
```